# Periodicity of bands in crystals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, crystals, states-of-matter

I am studying on the Ashcroft- Mermin Solid State Physics and at chap8 pag 141 it is said that *for given n, the eigenstates and eigenvalues are periodic functions of k in the reciprocal lattice* that is
$$E_{n, k+K} = E_{n,k}$$
and same for $\psi$.
I get the argument about the wave function, but not the one about energy. For example the energy of a free electron (the potential is 0 so it's periodic and we can apply bloch and develop wave functions with it) is different, $\hbar²k²/2m ≠ \hbar²(k-K)²/2m$.
Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: What is the period of the "periodic" potential $V=0$?

Comment: The potential U=0 satisfies $U(r+R)=U(r)$ for every R , so the Bloch Theorem may be applied (it is also used as an example of OK potential in the text, but it goes not further)

Comment: $K$ is defined by one of the reciprocal lattice vectors. What are these lattice vectors for the potential $V=0$?

Comment: Along the same lines, what is the first Brioullin zone for the potential $V=0$? Canonically, you would define Bloch waves by restricting to this region.